# Value of loss and accuracy does not change over Epochs

Tags: cnn

I am trying to work on a CNN model for churn. Here is my code. NO matter what optimizer I choose, change the learning rate, learning decay, loss function etc, losses and accuracy do not change over epoch.
I am feeding following array as input to model, which are encoded ( label encoded and then CSC)
x_train.shape =  (27999, 1, 500, 10)
y_train.shape =  (27999,)
x_test.shape =  (57540, 1, 500, 10)
y_test.shape =  (57540,)

Original input is a CSV file of shape (28770155, 11)

Code is as follows:

### label Encoder

lab=LabelEncoder()

lab1=LabelEncoder()

train_label=train_table.apply(lab.fit_transform)

test_label=test_table.apply(lab1.fit_transform)

one_hot_array = csc_matrix(train_label, dtype=np.int8).toarray()

one_hot_test = csc_matrix(test_label, dtype=np.int8).toarray()

## Fit now of rows as image

rows_per_image = 500

cols_per_image = oh_cols-1

cols_per_image_test = ot_cols-1

num_colors_per_pixel = 1

num_of_images = oh_rows // rows_per_image

num_of_images_test = ot_rows // rows_per_image

image_shape = (num_colors_per_pixel, rows_per_image, cols_per_image)

image_shape_test = (num_colors_per_pixel, rows_per_image, cols_per_image_test)

## Drop tail rows that wont fit into a 500 row image

truncated_one_hot_array = one_hot_array[:rows_per_image * num_of_images, :]

truncated_one_hot_test = one_hot_test[ :rows_per_image * num_of_images_test, :]

# x_train is the image array

x_train = truncated_one_hot_array[:, :-1].reshape(num_of_images,
image_shape[0], #num_colors_per_pixel,
image_shape[1], #rows_per_image,
image_shape[2]  #cols_per_image
187 )

x_test = truncated_one_hot_test[:, :-1].reshape(
       num_of_images_test,
       image_shape_test[0], #num_colors_per_pixel,
        image_shape_test[1], #rows_per_image,
        image_shape_test[2]  #cols_per_image
)

...Some code for Y train and Y test .....

## Model :

model = Sequential()

K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')  # th = (channels, rows, cols) ; tf = (rows, cols, channels)

model.add(Conv2D(20, (3, 3), input_shape = image_shape, activation= 'relu', padding="same" ))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(20, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32, activation= 'relu' ))

model.add(Dense(25, activation= 'relu' ))

model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid' ))

opt = SGD(lr =0.01,decay = 1e-6,momentum = 0.9)

model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy' , optimizer=opt,
               metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

print ('model.input_shape  ', model.input_shape)

model.summary()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
     validation_data =(x_test,y_test),
           epochs=10, # 20:1
           batch_size=8) #160 #change training epochs

model.input_shape   (None, 1, 500, 10)

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 500, 10)       200

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 20, 250, 5)        0

---

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 248, 3)        3620

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 20, 248, 3)        0

---

flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 14880)             0

---

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 32)                476192

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 25)                825

---

## dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 26

Total params: 480,863
Trainable params: 480,863
Non-trainable params: 0

---

WARNING:tensorflow:Variable *= will be deprecated. Use variable.assign_mul if you want assignment to the variable value or 'x = x * y' if you want a new python Tensor object.

Train on 27999 samples, validate on 57540 samples

Epoch 1/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 37s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5676 - acc: 0.8407 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 2/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5652 - acc: 0.8409 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 3/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5652 - acc: 0.8409 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 4/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5652 - acc: 0.8409 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 5/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5652 - acc: 0.8409 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 6/10
27999/27999 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/step - loss: 2.5652 - acc: 0.8409 - val_loss: 2.2765 - val_acc: 0.8588

Epoch 7/10.......

Kindly help. Tried all possible scenarios.